# How to deal with Restful resource when using Angular token auth with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, rest, devise

I'm using ng-token-auth on Angular and with devise-token-auth on Rails for authentication which works fine but there are occasionally I need to sent in id of the user or any other resource for `show` function in Rails `resource`

When I however request for `show` on User resource I don't have a way to find out id of the current user before it reaches the server to be sent as part of url in the request.

What is the recommended way to deal with this Restful routes situation when used with token authentication on Rails and Angular?

Comment: any update? I'm fighting the same issue